# How to get the value of a number embedded in text using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to find out the value of the numeric part from a string, where the string contains two parts, text and number. There is only one couple of such text. For example number01, data34 etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery not needed:

```
var myString = 'data34';
var myNumber = myString.match(/\d+/);
alert(myNumber);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have juust started jQuery and its really fun.